# Where can I find Icon sets for Unity?

Tags: unity, icons

I really dislike the default monochrome icons in Unity's global menu and in Thunderbird, but I haven't been able to find a source for alternative icons. Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GNOME-Look](http://gnome-look.org) has some icon sets that work with Unity, but in general you will be hard pressed to find a lot of good icon sets for now (the community's efforts are still gaining momentum in that regard).

Unfortunately, btw, most authors will not call their icon "Icon-Theme-(Unity)" or something similar, and you also may have to try the theme before you drive it, so to speak.

You can try [Faience](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Faience?content=144814) and [Awoken](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/AwOken?content=126344) (they are good monochrome themes for Unity).

### Previews:

[image: Faience]

[image: Awoken]
***(Images taken from the GNOME-Look.org previews)***

Comment: Thanks! I'm playing with these sets now. Any insights on how to apply those same icons (or find similar icons) for Thunderbird?

Comment: Thunderbird is a tricky one, because it *should* pull in your icon sets, but it seems not to do it completely. The best bet may be to tweak the userchrome.css file, but I'm not too knowledgeable on Thunderbird/Firefox theme tweaks :P.